# Only Remove Space Between two digits?

Tags: php, regex, datetime

2016-06-27 1 7:25:55 need to remove space between 1 and 7 give me some useful preg_replace expression for that. date format fix  2016-06-27 17:25:55.

Answer (score 3):

Use preg_replace function like below,

```
preg_replace('~\b(\d)\s(\d)\b~', '$1$2', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too

```
preg_replace('/([-\d]+\s\d)\s([\d:]+)/', '$1$2', $str);
```

Or Just

```
 preg_replace('/(\s\d)\s([\d:]+)/', '$1$2', $str);
```

Or even smaller

```
preg_replace('/(\s\d)\s/', '$1', $str);
```